# disable ssr for specific page in nuxt js

Tags: javascript, html, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

i have a web app universal by nuxt js.
mode : 'universal'

in blog/post/_slug.vue

by refresh get error :

TypeError
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

and in page : dashboard/post/new
by refresh get error :

TypeError Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Hi, please provide more information about your `blog/post/_slug.vue` and `dashboard/post/new` page - so we can look into it.

Comment: From my experience with Nuxt.js - I assumed that `blog/post/_slug.vue` page does some AJAX request in `created()` - so the page will load before the data is available, causing the error because it try to read `title` from `undefined` (the data being fetched).

Comment: in blog/post/_slug.vue  in routing nuxt js ok and data fetch from api but refresh TypeError  cannot read property 'title' of undefind.  in asyncData()  fetch data from api. 
by refresh not work asyncdata !

Comment: in mode : 'spa' all ok ! but in mode: 'universal' TypeError!

Comment: @phwt no solution for problem ??

Comment: use the methods and pass asyncData to the property and solve probleM. SOLVED!